# Iterate over two Pytorch tensors at once?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have two Pytorch tensors (really, just 1-D lists), `t1` and `t2`. Is it possible to iterate over them in parallel, i.e. do something like

`for a,b in zip(t1,t2)`
?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

For me (Python version 3.7.3 and PyTorch version 1.0.0) the zip function works as expected with PyTorch tensors:

```
>>> import torch
>>> t1 = torch.ones(3)
>>> t2 = torch.zeros(3)
>>> list(zip(t1, t2))
[(tensor(1.), tensor(0.)), (tensor(1.), tensor(0.)), (tensor(1.), tensor(0.))]
```

The `list` call is just needed to display the result. Iterating over `zip` works normally.

Comment: One additional piece of information that might be useful is your python version. IIRC, there were some updates to `dict`s in 3.5 which might be relevant for this. Not that I would recommend any older versions anyways...

Comment: @dennlinger I added my Python version (3.7.3). Interessting, I wasn't aware of this change.

Comment: what if the tensors have dimensions other than just being a list? like 16,3,84,84?

Comment: note that using zip, the output won't be tensor anymore which means you can't do it in gpu.

Answer (score 6):

Your can try:
`torch.stack(seq, dim=0, out=None) → Tensor`,

 for details see [pytoch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.stack)

Answer (score 3):

To **zip** tensors in **PyTorch** into one use `torch.stack` with `dim=1`

Example

```
t1 = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
t2 = torch.tensor([10, 20, 30])
t3 = torch.tensor([100, 200, 300])

res = torch.stack((t1, t2, t3), dim=1)
#output
#tensor([[  1,  10, 100],
#        [  2,  20, 200],
#        [  3,  30, 300]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to [concatenate](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat) them with `torch.cat(dim=1)`; then, you can iterate over the new tensor.

Comment: I thought about that, but is there really no way to just do a zip?